# Quoted Printable Email showing equal signs in certain email clients

Tags: email

I'm generating emails.  They Show up fine for me in gmail and Outlook 2010.  However, my client sees the = sign that gets added to the end of lines by the quoted-printable formatting.  It also eats the character on the next line, but then displaying the equal sign.

Example:

```
line that en=
ds like this
```

shows up like

```
line that en=s like this
```

(Note: The EOL character in my emails is just LF. No CR.)

I'm confirming what outlook version my client is using, but I think it's 2007. The email headers from her appear to come through Exchange 6.5.

My emails are created in php using the HtmlMimeMail5 library.  They are multipart emails, with the applicable section sent with:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

It appears I could just make sure nothing in my email reaches the line wrap at 76 characters, but that seems like the wrong way to solve the problem. Should the EOL character be different? (In emails from the client, the EOL character is simply a LF) Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know what the PHP library does, but in the end MIME mail must contain CR LF line endings. Obviously the client notices that = is not followed by a proper CR LF sequence, so it assumes that it is not a soft line break, but a character encoded in two hex digits, therefore it reads the next two bytes. It should notice that the next two bytes are not valid hex digits, so its behavior is wrong too, but we have to admit that at that point it does not have a chance to display something useful. They opted for the garbage in, garbage out approach.

Comment: It indeed turned out that my mail library sent only LF by default.  Adjusting that setting to CRLF did indeed fix the problem.