# Why is nodemailer corrupting my e-mail html?

Tags: nodemailer

I sent the following html via html with [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/):

```html
<html>
    <div>
        <div>The Archimandrite<br /><img src="cid:The Archimandrite" /></div>
    </div>
</html>
```

But when I look at the message in Gmail with "Show Original," I see the following html:

```html
<html>
    <div>
        <div>The Archimandrite<br /><img src=3D"cid:The Archimandrite" /></=
div>
    </div>
</html>
```

For some reason there's a random `3D` in the middle and there's a `=` at the end of one line.

What's going on here and how can I make nodemailer behave normally?

Comment: Maybe because  `=` is %3D urlencoded? Is it a bug?

Comment: I dont know anything about nodemailer, but just pointing out there's a few other things inbetween sending to nodemailer and looking at it in gmail, like the sending mailserver, gmail etc. If there was a way you could check what nodemailer is sending to the mailserver, that would identify the problem as nodemailer or not

Comment: It appears to only be an issue with lines that are over 75 characters. Somehow an `=` is getting inserted. I found a lot of results for this phenomenon online, but no solution yet...

Comment: `<br/>` and `<img/>` are invalid html, maybe gmail does something there while displaying your mail. you could use sth like https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener to catch your mails locally and inspect them without gmail etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand the equal sign '=' symbol in IMAP email text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621510/how-to-understand-the-equal-sign-symbol-in-imap-email-text)

Comment: Marian Theisen - I'm pretty sure `<br/>` and `<img/>` are valid html tags. Ouroborus - that is very helpful because it's great to now have a name for this: "quoted printable encoding." I was also able to uncover [this information about `libqp`](https://github.com/nodemailer/libqp#wrap-encoded-values). After using `libqp.wrap(html)`, I no longer get `=` transformed into `=3D`, so that's nice. However, I still get the `=` at the end of the lines. The embedded html works, and the `<img/>` shows up in the e-mail, but I also get the end-of-line `=` characters rendering in the body of the message.

Comment: Looks like it [may be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7936214/4476484) a termination character problem that the end-of-line `=` signs are showing up in the e-mail body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr

Use [nodemailer's `{ textEncoding: 'base64' }` option](https://nodemailer.com/message/#content-options).

### More information

I tried `textEncoding` at first, but for some reason it didn't seem to have an effect. Either I did something else wrong or I forgot to save the file before running the code, or *something* because it didn't work and I wrote off the option as useless.

I tried using the libqp package, as mentioned in the question comments. This helped with the escaped characters, but not with the newline issue.

I tried removing whitespace and replacing it with explicit `\n` characters.

I tried varying line lengths for the content.

I experimented with hard-wrapping my html to 75 characters so that it would fit and not get any `=` characters at all, but some of my html code required long lines.

Then I tried making my `cid` tags really long by appending `_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` to the end of them, and for some reason it worked fine when I did that.

I also tried adding in longer lines of text and those displayed properly.

I noticed that when I ran the code through GitHub Actions, the raw e-mail said the encoding was `7bit`, whereas the local runs said `qouted-printable`.

After many many combinations of the above attempts, I finally came back to the `textEncoding` option to try it again and it worked just fine.